# VBA, A lot of "IF", some error and variable case

Tags: excel, vba

HI I'm trying to simplifies this code and make it work, it's a verification code. Each time I got
"if Without End IF". I try with "Select Case", "Else IF, "else". I'm not really comfortable with those.

```
Sub Caption2_Click()
Dim page As Range, New_Name As Range, Input_PWD As String, Input_Txt As String

'Set page = Range("I3")
'Set New_Name = Range("J3")


'Input_PWD = InputBox("SVP entré le code ", "Demande d'activation")
 'Input_TX = InputBox("SVP entré le nouveau nom ", "Data Entry Form")

 ' If Input_PWD = 71234 Then

  'Range("D7").Select
If Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption <> Range("D7").Value Then
Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption = Range("D7").Value
Range("E7").Value = Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption 

If Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption <> Range("C8").Value Then
Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption = Range("D8").Value

If Sheets("XXX").HTTP.Caption <> Range("C9").Value Then
Sheets("XXX").HTTP.Caption = Range("D9").Value

If Sheets("XXX").WE.Caption <> Range("C10").Value Then
Sheets("XXX").WE.Caption = Range("D10").Value

If Sheets("XXX").NF.Caption <> Range("C11").Value Then
Sheets("XXX").NF.Caption = Range("D11").Value

If Sheets("XXX").AC.Caption <> Range("C12").Value Then
Sheets("XXX").AC.Caption = Range("D12").Value

'If Sheets("XXX").MU.Caption <> Range("C13").Value Then
'Sheets("XXX").MU.Caption = Range("D13").Value
End If
'If Input_PWD <> 71234 Then Exit Sub
'End If

End Sub
```

OTHER WAY TO SEE IT :

I may write it in the wong way, Basically I just want to compare all the value on the left to the value on the right and when it false, the caption name on the left change to the value on the right. So, it's maybe something like `If XXX.caption <> range("C8:C13") then xxxx.caption = Range(D8:D13) or = Offset(0,1)`

[image: Caption_name]

WB; HTTP;NF;AC ect are the name of my buttons (in propriety)

Thanks

Comment: What is the point of this: If Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption <> Range("D7").Value Then
Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption = Range("D7").Value? Modify Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption without checking, the cost will probably be lower and code will be more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to say by "Without Checking" ?

I want to use this code to change the caption on some button, so if i need to change many of them in a fast and simple way, i compared them to a range of cell. but each button have different title

Comment: You check if Caption is different from the one in the cell and if so you assign Caption=cell. Just doing caption=cell would end with the same effect. This only applies to first check in your code (the one with "D7"). In following lines it is different, although assuming that valuest in C and D columns are different Caption would be modified with the same value every time tho macro is run. If values in C and D are the same check is not needed (as with D7 check)

Answer (score 2):

In VBA an if block looks like:

```
If someTest Then doSomething 'all on one line: no End If required
```

Or

```
If someTest Then
    DoSomething
End If
```

You need `End If` when using more than a single line.

Comment: THanks, but I already know that. I forgot to add "End sub" in the end of my question. I add End if becauxe excel told me..

Comment: That's not how you wrote the code in your question. You have only one `End If` and a whole lot of `If` 's, none of which are single-line statements.

Answer (score 0):

Tim already answered part of your question.
Now below is how you determine single line statements.

**Example1:**
Below is a non-single line `IF statement`:

```
If Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption <> Range("C8").Value Then
    Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption = Range("D8").Value
```

To make it single-line `IF statement` not requiring `End If`:

```
If Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption <> Range("C8").Value Then Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption = Range("D8").Value
```

or use line continuation character `_` like this:

```
If Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption <> Range("C8").Value Then _
    Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption = Range("D8").Value
```

**Example2:**
Now consider below `IF Statement`:

```
If Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption <> Range("D7").Value Then
    Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption = Range("D7").Value
    Range("E7").Value = Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption
```

Is it possible to make it a single line `IF statement`?
Of course. You need to use statement separation character `:` like below:

```
If Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption <> Range("D7").Value Then Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption = Range("D7").Value: Range("E7").Value = Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption
```

Above is equivalent to:

```
If Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption <> Range("D7").Value Then _
    Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption = Range("D7").Value: _
    Range("E7").Value = Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption
```

Hope this clears some of your confusions.
I bet you now know how to correct your code?

BTW, I still suggest you use `Select Case` for multiple conditions.
I re-write your code using `Select Case` below:

```
Select Case True
Case Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption <> Range("D7").Value
    Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption = Range("D7").Value
    Range("E7").Value = Sheets("XXX").GL.Caption

Case Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption <> Range("C8").Value
    Sheets("XXX").WB.Caption = Range("D8").Value

Case Sheets("XXX").HTTP.Caption <> Range("C9").Value
    Sheets("XXX").HTTP.Caption = Range("D9").Value

Case Sheets("XXX").WE.Caption <> Range("C10").Value
    Sheets("XXX").WE.Caption = Range("D10").Value

Case Sheets("XXX").NF.Caption <> Range("C11").Value
    Sheets("XXX").NF.Caption = Range("D11").Value

Case Sheets("XXX").AC.Caption <> Range("C12").Value
    Sheets("XXX").AC.Caption = Range("D12").Value
End Select
```

I bet you'll agree it's cleaner?
Hope above helps.

Comment: Hi
I'not really understand the use of " : ", " Select case " seem to work BUT, in the final only the first part work (or do want I want)/activate.
I add some exemple in my question, hope that help

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand how you set up GL, WB, HTTP...  are they declared as buttons ?

i did a little testing around and came up with :

```
sheets("XXX").buttons("ButtonName").caption = Range("C9").Value 'you may want to add a sheets("XXX") before Range("C9")...
```

to see the buttonname, select the button and look at the upper left of the excel window.